# procdump usage for visual C++ application 2010 for creating crash dump

Tags: visual-c++, procdump

I tried installing procdump tool from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

when i open the command window and run procdump exe as:

```
procdump.exe -g -e -w -ma test.exe
```

it just shows waiting for process names test.exe

it doesnot create any dump file at all.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: also, please let me know if there is any other better tool to create crash dump files whenever there is any crash. my application is a server running on a machine and its very difficult to debug the crash as many users are connected to it and there is absolutely no idea how to reproduce the crash.  any suggestions/comments are most welcome.

Comment: `-w Wait for the specified process to launch if it's not running.` so it should wait?

Comment: @Wimmel : it should wait if it is not runninng but in this command i am executing it with the procdump command , but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

The [usage page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) includes the following options;

```
-w  Wait for the specified process to launch if it's not running.
-x  Launch the specified image with optional arguments.
```

The options you use, include `-w`, but do not include `-x`, so procdump will wait until test.exe is running, but will not start it itself.

Comment: when i use -x option as:

Comment: procdump.exe -g -e -w -ma -x crash.dmp test.exe it shows error like: no directory exists crash.dmp

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked after a bit of trial and error : the command below works perfectly fine:

procdump.exe -g -e -w -ma exename

it basically waits for the process to start and once the process crashes , it creates a dump. Thankyou all for giving me pointers . i learnt something new :)